# Why is my internet speed slower on my PC than my Laptop

Tags: networking, ethernet, speed, internet-speed

I have a Gigabit switch

and through it i connected Cat6 cable to my laptop and the speedtest gives me around 260mb/s which is the appropriate speed

but when i connect the same cable to my PC which also supports gigabit ethernet it gives me between 180mb/s to 200mb/s

I have tested both devices multiple times and it's always the same result.

Is it because of the ethernet port on PC has some interference? or what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Is the laptop newer and the desktop older?  it could be the card in the desktop that is slower.  Try a high speed USB Ethernet Adapter to see.  Note:  I just tested both my machines (both the same age, newish, Desktop, Laptop) and got the same speed from both.

Comment: The laptop is definitely older it was released on 2012 its Fujitsu lifebook ah352/g21
The PC has an Asrock Steel Legend B450M motherboard for AMD Ryzen platform

Comment: You may wish to try another adapter in the Desktop.

Comment: Is there any possible culprits beside the ethernet port on the PC? Because i do not have other adapters on it except the motherboard's one.

If thats the case then i could try buy an ethernet PCIE card and put it in the desktop

Comment: That is hard to say. If Windows 10, you could try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: It is almost impossible to say with the given information. Working for an ISP, I have experienced MANY things that can cause speedtests to be inaccurate, including anti-virus or other security software, different browsers, different OS's, different CPU loads, different RAM, different drivers, cabling issues, and many other things.